# Bash variable not iterated in output redirection after curl or wget

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, wget

I have came across weird behavior of Bash variable in redirection after `curl` command:

```
curl -s 'https://www.google.com' > "./out_curl_$((++i)).txt"
```

I created following test script `./curl_test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/env bash
i=0
curl -s 'https://www.google.com' > "./out_curl_$((++i)).txt"
curl -s 'https://www.google.com' > "./out_curl_$((++i)).txt"
echo "This is i: ${i}"
ls -1 ./out_curl_*.txt

j=0
echo 'hello' > "./out_echo_$((++j)).txt"
echo 'hello' > "./out_echo_$((++j)).txt"
echo "This is j: ${j}"
ls -1 ./out_echo_*.txt

exit 0
```

Output:

```
$ ./curl_test.sh
This is i: 0
./out_curl_1.txt
This is j: 2
./out_echo_1.txt
./out_echo_2.txt
```

Expected output:

```
$ ./curl_test.sh
This is i: 2
./out_curl_1.txt
./out_curl_2.txt
This is j: 2
./out_echo_1.txt
./out_echo_2.txt
```

Please does anybody know why is that? What already tried out:

`wget` has the same behavior:

```
wget -q -O - 'https://www.google.com' > "./out_wget_$((++k)).txt"
```

Encapsulating `curl` into sub-shell `( ... )` does not help.

This 2 liner of course works:

```
((i++))
curl -s 'https://www.google.com' > "./out_curl_${i}.txt"
```

Thank You for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing redirections is typically done **after** forking off a subprocess, but necessarily done **before** using the `execve()` to hand over control from the shell to the new executable (in your case `curl` or `wget`) being run in that process.

Because you've already `fork()`'d, changes to variables are happening in the new process's context, and aren't propagated back to the parent.

This doesn't apply to the default `echo` because it's a shell built-in, and is thus in-process (requiring no `fork` at all), but it *does* apply to `/bin/echo` on shells implemented in this manner (which the POSIX standard neither prohibits nor requires).

---

A simpler reproducer for this issue -- showing that it applies to *all* non-builtin commands -- follows, as generated with bash 3.2.57 and also reproduced against 4.4.23:

```
$ i=0; echo >>"test$((++i)).tmp"; echo "$i"
1
$ i=0; /bin/echo >>"test$((++i)).tmp"; echo "$i"
0
```

---

If you want to work around this problem, you can do so by performing the redirection for an entire command group:

```
$ i=0; { /bin/echo; } >>"test$((++i)).tmp"; echo "$i"
1
```

The `{ ...; }` construct performs redirection for the entire block of commands, and thus executes the redirection *before* forking off the child process which will be replaced with `/bin/echo`.

Comment: Thank You very much Charles for explanation. Executing commands curl, wget as a group { ... ; } works as expected and as You described.